# The use of the word "do" in a sentence

Tags: word-usage, auxiliary-verbs, do-support

Can someone please explain to me the role and function of the word *do* in this sentence?

> But advertisements **do** not only give information, they also try to influence our emotions.

Comment: Hey, I think this question would get better answers over on our sister site, [ELL.se]. I've voted to move it there for you.

Comment: Suggested reading: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Do-support

Comment: The reworded question can be answered [here](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/grammar/british-grammar/not-only-but-also). The sentence can be better phrased without *do*. So, it's the usage of *not only... but also*.

Answer (score 2):

The negative of "gives" is **{do/does} not give**.  In English you cannot just say {he/she/they/it} **not give(s).**

Negative constructions  **normally, generally, usually** require *do support*,  which Damkerng supplied a link to explain:

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Do-support

Please read that article.

But, as Maulik pointed out, your example is a case of the "not only.....but also..." which **does not require**  *do support*.

(Note bolded example of *do support* in the sentence above!)